# In Protobuf, are double or float types fixed size when serialized?

Tags: java, geometry, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Are '**double**' and '**float**' data types fixed size in Protobuf? Do they occupy a fixed number of bytes (say 8 or 4 bytes) when serialized no matter what value (big or small) they actually keep? I want to use one of them to keep **latitude** and **longitude**. If they're fixed, then I think it makes sense to use '**float**' instead as it seems to be enough?

Comment: Yes, byte size is fixed

Comment: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#non-varints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google protobuf encoding docs](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#varints), `double` will be fixed of 8-bytes, and `float` is fixed 4-bytes when serialized

> Non-varint numeric types are simple – double and fixed64 have wire type I64, which tells the parser to expect a fixed eight-byte lump of data. We can specify a double record by writing 5: 25.4, or a fixed64 record with 6: 200i64. In both cases, omitting an explicit wire type implies the I64 wire type.

> Similarly float and fixed32 have wire type I32, which tells it to expect four bytes instead. The syntax for these consists of adding an i32 prefix. 25.4i32 will emit four bytes, as will 200i32. Tag types are inferred as I32.
> float would depend on your specific needs for precision:

When it comes to representing latitude and longitude, your choice between `double` and `float` would depend on your specific needs for precision:

- A float provides approximately 6-9 decimal digits of precision. In the context of latitude and longitude, this would allow you to specify a location to within about a meter.
- A double, on the other hand, provides approximately 15-17 decimal digits of precision. This level of precision is generally more than you would need for geolocation data.

In summary, if you don't require extremely high precision, a float should be sufficient for storing latitude and longitude coordinates. Using float over double could also save some space, especially if you have a large dataset of such coordinates to store or transmit.

I hope this helps clarify your question!

Comment: Thank you Amit. Yes, there'll be actually a large number of records per second transferred between few microservices using Protobuf and Kafka topics. That's why I was curious and concerned.

Comment: But seems like float has a limitation of keeping precisions because it's 32bits or whatever, depending on the integer part of the value. For example, 31.987654f is fine, but 32.987654f changes to 32.987656! Or 1.000001f is fine, but 50.000001f turns to 50.0!

Comment: This is a classic issue with floating-point arithmetic in computer science. The more complex or lengthy the number, the more likely you are to encounter rounding errors due to limitations in bit size. This can be a critical issue depending on your application.

For example, if you're using these numbers to represent geographical coordinates, a slight change in the 6th or 7th decimal place might not significantly alter the location. However, in applications requiring very high precision, such as scientific computing, these small changes could be unacceptable.